# Is the following set a semiring?

Tags: measure-theory

Is the set:

$\mathcal{M}=\{(-\infty, b], b \in \mathbb{R}\}$

a semi-Ring?

In our definition, a semi-Ring is considered an algebraic structure with:

$(1) \, \emptyset \in \mathcal{M} \\\\
(2) \, A, B \in \mathcal{M} \Rightarrow A \, \cap B \in \mathcal{M} \\\\
(3) \, A,B \in \mathcal{M}, A \subset B \Rightarrow \exists n\in \mathbb{N}, \exists C_1,\dots,C_n \in \mathcal{M}, C_i \cap C_j = \emptyset \, (i \neq j) \,\, B \setminus A = \sum_{i=1}^n C_i$

Can anyone help me out? I personally suspect that the second condition cannot be fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

Neither (1) or (3) holds.

There's no real $b$ such that $(-\infty,b]$  is empty (it contains $b$).

Also, the difference of two such sets is
$$(-\infty, b]\setminus(-\infty,a]=(a,b]$$
if $a<b$ and empty otherwise, can't be expressed as a union of (finitely many) such sets, because each element of $\mathcal M$ is unbounded from below, and so must be their union, whereas the intervals $(a,b]$ and the empty set are bounded.

Comment: alright, I guess my ideas were right then. Would you agree if I suggest that also (2) does not hold, arguing just as you did?

Comment: No, actually (2) does hold, $(-\infy,a]\cap(-\infty,b]=(-\infty,\,\min(a,b)]$.

Comment: Ah s***, of course. Classical error in reasoning! Thank you Berci.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not "whether", but "where". Yes, given the extended real numbers. No, given the real numbers.